# Service Setup missing in new developer org Spring '17

Tags: lightning, spring17, service-console

I tried to test the new Lightning service console but I can't seem to find where I need to activate it.

In the Spring '17 release notes they talk about Service Setup which should be located under the gear icon but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I checked the developer org and I do have service cloud enabled, I am a service cloud user also... but I am seem to miss the menu item.

Does anybody experience the same?

Comment: Is your question duplicate of [Confused: Lightning Service Console only for Salesforce Classic?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146178/confused-lightning-service-console-only-for-salesforce-classic)

Comment: It is not duplicate as i saw this question but conclusion of this question is...Yes there is a new Lightning Service Console and here are the release notes. but i checked the release notes and my follow up question is where do you find that Service Setup menu. Does anybody has tested this out already.

Comment: Ah ok, I have retracted close vote. Make sense!

Answer (score 0):

An update from my side and partial answer.

I created a sandbox from an existing production org with service cloud users. Switched this to LEX and then on the app launcher you have a Service Console app. When you click on that app and then click on the gear icon, you do have a service setup menu item.

[image]
[image]

I still could not accomplish the same on a newly created developer org